# Fading in images as they scroll into the viewport using datasrc, live and the Inview plugin.

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm pretty close to cracking this, or cracking up, i'm not sure which yet. Maybe both.

I have a series of images loading on the page (some quite big) via an infinite scroll javascript (the only one that works with tumblr apprently, on the *entire world wide web*, nice) http://syndex.me

After much,much research I've come to find a fork of the [inview plugin](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) which seems to be what I'm after. I have two ways of using it, each have big problems.

---

**Method 1**

The problem with this method is that it i get hundreds of console logs. I thought the whole point of this plugin was to doStuff when a very specific event happened. ie an img came into view. I have to use live, as imgs are being loaded dynamically. I have tried to unbind, stop propogation etc, to no avail.

```
$('img').live('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
  if (isInView) {
      //fadein the image
      console.log("I've just done something")
  }
  });
```

---

**Method 2** (demo at http://syndex.me)

The images "jump" into position as soon as they have finished loading (*position*, not opacity).

I can imagine people saying, yes thats because the browser does not know the height of the image until it's 100% loaded. But I've seen countless sites manage to do this. Maybe i need to do this without using "load" then? But what would that be?

```
$(function() {
 $('img[data-src]').live('inview', function(event, isVisible) {
  if (!isVisible) { return; }

  var img = $(this);

  // Show a smooth animation
  img.load(function() { img.parent().animate({ opacity: 1 }); });

  // Change src
  img.attr('src', img.attr('data-src'));

  // Remove it from live event selector
  img.removeAttr('data-src');
  console.log(img.height())
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so what if you try this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload.

You can achieve the same very easily... Good luck!!

===================================== EDIT ========================================

OK, so I gone through http://syndex.me, and they are not loading a particular image, instead they are loading an entire page via ajax if you check.

Well, lets come back to the problem. If you want to track how to track if some element is coming in the viewport, then this is quite simple.

You just need to get the dimention of the window (height if vertical scroll is working here).
Bind scroll event on the window and check for the element.offsetTop and compare it with document.body.scrollTop - window.innerHeight to know if element.offsetTop is greater or not. If yes, tada! that is in the viewport.

Set the data-src attribute in the image with the original src initially and on the [tada!] condition, set it to src attribute and remove the data-src attribute.

while setting the src attribute in the image, always check if data-src is available or not, so that when you remove the data-src, that re-setting doesn't happen multiple times.

well structure should be:

```
var winHeight = window.innerHeight,
    winPos = document.body.scrollTop,
    elePos = element.offsetTop;

window on scroll = function(){
    winPos = document.body.scrollTop; // get the current position
    winHeight = window.innerHeight; // get the current height as what if window is resized

    if(elePos > winPos - winHeight){
        // Tada! this is in the viewport

        if(image.getAttrubute("data-src")){
            image.setAttribute("src")  = image.getAttrubute("data-src");
            image.removeAttribute("data-src");
        }
    }
}
```

By Default, you can put a placeholder on the every image, so that doesn't throw error on w3 validations.

On the image, you can bind load event to make it animated. for that keep it invisible initially.

> This is a rough (like pseudo) code, not the actual one. so see the logic not the syntax.

Well, I think this will help you!!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.